# "Runtime errors might occur when converting 'system.linq.IQueryable(of String)' to 'String'

Tags: vb.net, linq, global-variables

I am creating a feature where I allow a user to type in an email address and click "Search".  This will search my database and return the email address, which I will then use in other methods to randomly generate passwords and email them.  Language is ASP.VB and database is LINQ.  I am getting an error to say "Runtime errors might occur when converting 'system.linq.IQueryable(of String)' to 'String' "

The code segment is:

```
 Protected Sub btnSearchEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles         btnSearchEmail.Click

    Dim db As New DatabaseDataClassesDataContext()

    GlobalVariables.SearchUserEmail = txtSearchEmail.Text

    GlobalVariables.CurrentEmailAddress = (From u In db.User_Signons
                                           Where u.Email = SearchUserEmail
                                           Select u).Distinct


End Sub
```

Any thoughts on how I can get around this.  The global variables are both "As String" and the field in the DB is varchar.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `Distinct` call returns a sequence of strings, and the property you are assigning to is just one single string.  Consider using `First` or `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Distinct`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I changed it to "first", and tried "firstordefault" also but now I am getting the error "Cannot convert type User_Signon to String". User_Signon is the table not the field.

Comment: @Gavin: Change `Select u` to `Select u.Email`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
GlobalVariables.CurrentEmailAddress = (From u In db.User_Signons
                                       Where u.Email = SearchUserEmail
                                       Select u).Distinct
```

`Distinct` returns a collection of distinct values.  If you just want one value use

```
var user = (From u In db.User_Signons
            Where u.Email = SearchUserEmail
            Select u).First

GlobalVariables.CurrentEmailAddress = user.Email

' Do something with password
```

Note that :

1. This only gives you the first value (obviously)
2. It will throw an exception if there are NO results (use `FirstOrDefault` to return a default value (`null` for strings) if that is a legitimate possibility.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I changed it to "first", and tried "firstordefault" also but now I am getting the error "Cannot convert type User_Signon to String".  User_Signon is the table not the field.

Comment: Which field do you want to return?  Seems silly to return `u.EMail` when you're searching for records that match a known value.

Comment: the premise is that the email is the unique identifier in the table.  For passwords, the user enters an email address.  This is searched against the database for the record and a password is generated and emailed to the address.  it seems to have no errors in the code now, except it won't launch ha.  one step forward two steps back

Comment: My point is do you just need the email address or the whole record?  It's pointless to say "find the record where e-mail address is "A" and give me the email address".  You already know the email address will be "A"!

Comment: That is true.  My thinking (coding newbie btw) is that for the user to log in to the system the password will have be associated with them.  The 'User_Signon' table contains 'Email' and 'Password' so i figure the password will have to be generated and associated to the email address, and just typing this I realise that my code does non of this